# Python - counting words without utilizing built in functions or importing libraries

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with this assignment... I'm attempting to count multiple occurances of a word(s) in a text file.

```
#most common word
fh = open("romeo.txt")
master_list = fh.read().split()
print(len(master_list))
compare_list = []
count_list = []
for word in master_list:
    if word not in compare_list:
        compare_list.append(word)
        count_list.append(1)
    else:
        for rw in range(len(compare_list)):
            for r in master_list:
                if compare_list[rw] == r :
                    count_list[rw] += 1

print(len(count_list))
print(count_list)
```

This is the data from the text file romeo(dot)txt
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

Comment: It would be easier to use a dictionary where key:value is word:count. Also, you may need to remove newlines from your file lines.

Comment: thankyou.  Unfortunately my professor won't allow us to use dict(), but thank you for the strip() suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead of a list. When you see each word, check if it's in the dictionary, if not add it else increment it's value.

Comment: Unfortunately, my professor won't allow us to use dict() for this assignment. but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this block

```
    if word not in compare_list:
        compare_list.append(word)
        count_list.append(1)
    else:
        for rw in range(len(compare_list)):
            for r in master_list:
                if compare_list[rw] == r :
                    count_list[rw] += 1
```

The `else` clause is executed when `word` is found in `compare_list`. So the behaviour should be to find it's index, then increment the corresponding index in `count_list` - you start by iterating through indexes of `compare_list` which is good, but then instead of comparing it to the current `word`, you start another iteration through `master_list`. Take out the `for r in master_list:` loop and just compare `compare_list[rw]` to `word` and I think you'll get there.

As others have noted, a `dict` would be a better structure for storing results - but it's hard to tell from your question if this would be "against the rules".

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.  And yes, dict() are not allowed as well.  I'll give you suggestion and shot and see if I can finish the program from that point.  Your explanation of the else statement really opened my eyes to the LOGIC behind the coding!